# Removing the status bar in my app

Tags: iphone

I'm making an small game for iPhone in openGL.

First I removed the "status bar" by writting

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Which worked, but only removed the status bar when my app began to run. Then I modified my project.plist

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

And now the status bar is never show, just how I wanted. The problem is that I'm reading touches without problem in any portion of the screen, except for the zone where the status bar used to be.

```
// This method deals with events when one or more fingers touch the screen
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [myProject newTouch:touches withEvent:event];   
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];
}

// This method deals with events when one or more fingers moves while touching the screen
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [myProject movingTouch:touches withEvent:event  ];
}

// This method deals with events when one or more fingers stops touching the screen
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [myProject oldTouchEnded:touches withEvent:event  ];
}

// This method deals with events when the system is interrupted ( for example an incomming call)
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // 
}
```

I guess that hiding the bar is not enough and it must be removed, but how can I do it ?, or there Is another solution ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  It happens in the simulator, and on the device -- iPhone 3GS, OS 3.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

What's the size of the view you're reading in? Sometimes people hide the status bar but forget to resize their view to cover the appropriate area. The complete screen is 320x480 - make sure your height is the full 480px, not 460 or smaller.

Comment: Yep, It's 320 X 480, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the simulator: it doesn't register touches where the status bar is (or would be). It works properly on the device, though.

Are you testing on the simulator or on the device?

Comment: The problem happens both in the device and the simulator.